# how override value from subchart - using null from parentchart in HELM

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am working on charts.
It consists of :

- Main chart (parent chart) contains the application
- 2 subcharts (mongo, redis)

The chart comes ready made with bitnami distribution.
I need to override runAsUser: 1001 with subchart with null value coming from parent chart.

I tried using option --set, use empty value or 0, but always get override value with value from subchart.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  A couple of values you might want to set get evaluated as "false" for purposes of `if` or `default` checks (I've run into trouble trying to manually set `replicas: 0` in some cases) and you need specific handling for these.